# d3d9 createdevice to obtain vtable black screen after alt tabbing

Tags: c++, hook, directx-9

So I want to hook directx 9 in a game. The game has 3 modes: fullscreen, borderless window, windowed mode. I use a dummy device method to obtain vtable then hook endscene with minhook. everything works fine in borderless window mode, however, in fullscreen mode when I alt tab from the game and then open it again the only thing I see is black screen. Sometimes It's just a tiny black rectangle in the left top corner of my screen, sometimes the entire screen is black. This happens even without the hook. Just creating a dummy device without actually hooking anything and alt tabbing out and then going back dyes my screen black. Of course I could just run the game in borderless window mode, but that would be a slight FPS loss, which I'd rather avoid. So, what do I need to do to avoid that black-screen-on-alt-tab-thing? Forgot to mention: if instead of alt+tabbing I use ctrl+alt+delete, then when I open the game again everything is fine. So as a last resort I could just make a habit of using ctrl+alt+del instead of alt+tab but that would be pretty weird, wouldn't it?
Here's how I create the device and copy the vtable:

```
WNDCLASSEX wCl;
wCl.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wCl.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wCl.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc;
wCl.cbClsExtra = 0;
wCl.cbWndExtra = 0;
wCl.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
wCl.hIcon = NULL;
wCl.hCursor = NULL;
wCl.hbrBackground = NULL;
wCl.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wCl.lpszClassName = L"whatever";
wCl.hIconSm = NULL;
::RegisterClassEx(&wCl);
HWND window = ::CreateWindow(wCl.lpszClassName, L"shit", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 100, 100, NULL, NULL, wCl.hInstance, NULL);
HMODULE d3dll;
if ((d3dll = ::GetModuleHandle(L"d3d9.dll")) == NULL)
{
    ::DestroyWindow(window);
    ::UnregisterClass(wCl.lpszClassName, wCl.hInstance);
}
void* Direct3DCreate9;
if ((Direct3DCreate9 = ::GetProcAddress(d3dll, "Direct3DCreate9")) == NULL)
{
    ::DestroyWindow(window);
    ::UnregisterClass(wCl.lpszClassName, wCl.hInstance);
}
LPDIRECT3D9 direct3D9;
if ((direct3D9 = ((LPDIRECT3D9(__stdcall*)(uint32_t))(Direct3DCreate9))(D3D_SDK_VERSION)) == NULL)
{
    ::DestroyWindow(window);
    ::UnregisterClass(wCl.lpszClassName, wCl.hInstance);
}
D3DDISPLAYMODE displayMode;
if (direct3D9->GetAdapterDisplayMode(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, &displayMode) < 0)
{
    ::DestroyWindow(window);
    ::UnregisterClass(wCl.lpszClassName, wCl.hInstance);
}
pp.BackBufferWidth = 0;
pp.BackBufferHeight = 0;
pp.BackBufferFormat = displayMode.Format;
pp.BackBufferCount = 0;
pp.MultiSampleType = D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE;
pp.MultiSampleQuality = NULL;
pp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
pp.hDeviceWindow = window;
pp.Windowed = 1;
pp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = 0;
pp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;
pp.Flags = NULL;
pp.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz = 0;
pp.PresentationInterval = 0;
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 device;
if (direct3D9->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
window, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING | D3DCREATE_DISABLE_DRIVER_MANAGEMENT, &pp, &device) < 0) // I think this is the culprit.
{
    direct3D9->Release();
    ::DestroyWindow(window);
    ::UnregisterClass(wCl.lpszClassName, wCl.hInstance);
}
vmt = (uint64_t*)::calloc(119, sizeof(uint64_t));
::memcpy(vmt, *(uint64_t * *)device, 119 * sizeof(uint64_t));

direct3D9->Release();
direct3D9 = NULL;
device->Release();
device = NULL;

::DestroyWindow(window);
::UnregisterClass(wCl.lpszClassName, wCl.hInstance);
```

So, how do I fix this? Am I perhaps creating the device the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use GetProcAddress() you can just call the d3d9 functions directly, they will be properly resolved.

CreateWindow() is unnecessary, just use EnumWindows to get the actual game window and then pass that handle to CreateDevice.

D3DCREATE_DISABLE_DRIVER_MANAGEMENT is unnecessary.

You should check the return of CreateDevice by checking if it is equal to S_OK.

Here is some code that many people are using without issue, I hope it solves your problem.

```cpp
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsCallback(HWND handle, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD wndProcId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, &wndProcId);

    if (GetCurrentProcessId() != wndProcId)
        return TRUE; // skip to next window

    window = handle;
    return FALSE; // window found abort search
}

HWND GetProcessWindow()
{
    window = NULL;
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsCallback, NULL);
    return window;
}

bool GetD3D9Device(void** pTable, size_t Size)
{
    if (!pTable)
        return false;

    IDirect3D9* pD3D = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    if (!pD3D)
        return false;

    IDirect3DDevice9* pDummyDevice = NULL;

    // options to create dummy device
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp = {};
    d3dpp.Windowed = false;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = GetProcessWindow();

    HRESULT dummyDeviceCreated = pD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, d3dpp.hDeviceWindow, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &pDummyDevice);

    if (dummyDeviceCreated != S_OK)
    {
        // may fail in windowed fullscreen mode, trying again with windowed mode
        d3dpp.Windowed = !d3dpp.Windowed;

        dummyDeviceCreated = pD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, d3dpp.hDeviceWindow, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &pDummyDevice);

        if (dummyDeviceCreated != S_OK)
        {
            pD3D->Release();
            return false;
        }
    }

    memcpy(pTable, *reinterpret_cast<void***>(pDummyDevice), Size);

    pDummyDevice->Release();
    pD3D->Release();
    return true;
}
```